# Can I send data from static website which is host on firebase to node js server which is hosted on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webserver, web-deployment, webdeploy

### Can I send data using from a static website which is host on firebase to node js server which is hosted on Heroku

**I have some issues with that**

1. After deploy I post simple data from Html which hosted on firebase to the server on Heroku
2. It showing cors was blocked and it doesn't show any data
3. After some repeated search I start using the **cors** module in node but still not working
4. Please tell me is it possible operation or not
   **This is my server-side which hosted on Heroku**

```
    const express = require('express')
    const path = require('path')
    const cors = require('cors')
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
    const app = express()
    const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'https://https://sample-377b8.web.app',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 ,// For legacy browser support
    methods: "GET, PUT"
    }
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')))
  app.use(express.json({limit:'1mb'}))
  
    let data;
  
    app.post('/',cors(corsOptions),(req,res)=>{
   
    data = req.body
    console.log(data)
    res.send({
    "success":"200 response",
    "res":"You are now just talked with server" 
     })})
     app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

**This is my code on HTML on firebase hosted**

```
  document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click',async()=>{
           let data = {lat,lon}
            await fetch('https://demoserver-app.herokuapp.com/',{mode:"no-cors"},{
            method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
       headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
           }).then( async (dat) =>{
               const res = await dat.json()
               document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = res.success
               document.getElementById('anotherres').innerHTML = res.res
               
           })
       })
```

****Is it possible to interact with each other ****
please give some solution with these problems it helps a lot for further project